# Visual Studio 2015 Community Next/Previous SplitPanel shortcut doesn't work?

Tags: visual-studio, splitview, visual-studio-community

I have two windows open in a vertical split. All I'm trying to do is switch between them from the keyboard. There's a command to do this in the Keyboard Shortcuts called `NextSplitPane` and `PreviousSplitPane` but they don't seem to be doing anything.

What am I missing? Is there another way to switch between views?

Comment: Works on my machine.

Comment: Tried it on 4 machines, default shortcuts F6 and Shift-F6, changing it to different keys, didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure it is a split window, not two tab groups or design/code?

Comment: Hmm, I right click a tab and select "New Vertical Tab Group". That's the only way I know of to split. Is there a different way?

Comment: I've tried Window | Split, the shortcut works. But It seems to split horizontally and stores it per tab which is pretty useless. I just want a Vim/Emacs/Sublime like split.

Answer (score 0):

Using this hacked version of VSStreamliner is the only thing that seemed to work for me.

https://github.com/lrperlmu/VSStreamliner2015